# Python serial read/write via RS-485

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, rs485

I have problem with serial reading/writting via RS-485. I wanted to check transmission Raspberry Pi and FTDI. FTDI is plugged to Raspberry via USB and also to RS-485 adapter.

Now I have two devices ttyUSB0 and ttyS0.

```
success=0
rsPin=22 #physical PIN 15 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(rsPin,GPIO.OUT)
d1 = open_port("/dev/ttyUSB0")
d2 = open_port("/dev/ttyS0")
data = "data"
while True:
    GPIO.output(rsPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    x=d2.read(d2.inWaiting())
    time.sleep(1)
    d1.write(data)
    if x:
       print x
       success+=1
       GPIO.output(rxPin, GPIO.LOW)
       y = d1.read(d1.inWaiting())
       time.sleep(1)
       d2.write(x)
       if y:
          print y
          success+=1
          if y==data and success==2:
              print "success"
              exit(1)
          else:
              print "error"
              exit(1)
```

The program doesn't work properly, when I run first time program, and probadly gets infinity loop, when I run again it shows me first data but later shows also duplicates data and error :

```
d2.write(wrdata)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 554, in write
raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(v))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I think that I probadly bad set direction RTS, should I use setRTS with GPIO.output to set direction RTS?

Comment: `d2 = open_port("/dev/ttyS0")` don't use static address. need create handshake communication before use.

Comment: @dsgdfg are there examples about handshake communication? U mean

`ser = serial.Serial(
                port="dev/ttyUSB0",
                baudrate = 9600,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                timeout=1,
                rtscts=0
           )`

Comment: Scan all available serial ports and send echo `who are you` and `ttys0 isn't compatible RS485(it is UART port)`

Comment: how I can use that echo? I checked `ls /dev/ | grep tty` and it returns me many of ttyN (N - numbers) and ttyAMA0, ttyprintk, ttyS0 and ttyUSB0

Comment: i know TTYUSB work very well, so this port is listener (corrector), if received any data send "you got me\n". On stack owerflow : `how to scan serial ports on linux ?`

Comment: u wrote that I won't use static adress. So how I should use that? Echoing all /dev/ttyUSB ports and use available?

Comment: @dsgdfg ttyUSB is also transmitter, he is sending data in first IF in WHILE loop

Comment: **get full-duplex rs485 converter !(only 3$(USD))** I'm sure you can't do the read-write schedule. don't waste your time !

Comment: @dsgdfg I don't understand that I should get rs485 converter. It's not possible to make RS-485 transmission with RS-485 adapter? Im still don't undestand why I can't use /dev/ttyS0, reading is working but writting from ttyS0 to ttyUSB0 isnt :( I thought that I should just setRTS or GPIO.output(rxPIN, LOW/HIGH) to properly make transmission. Im using a FT232h which is converter from USB to RS-485